# unknown symbol __class_create (err 0)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

This is probably a stupid question, but I looked for hours online and couldn't find an answer...

I'm writing a kernel module that also creates a character device. It compiles with no errors and warnings but when I try `sudo insmod my_mod.ko` I get:

`insmod: error inserting 'my_mod.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module`

and when I try to look at `dmesg` I see:

```
my_mod: Unknown symbol __class_create (err 0)
my_mod: Unknown symbol device_create_file (err 0)
my_mod: Unknown symbol device_create (err 0)
```

I'm guessing that I missed an `include` but I can't find which...

What are the includes needed?

My includes are currently:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
```

Comment: Maybe you missing license, something like that : MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

Comment: @Dabo I posted a similar answer without reading your comment. If you post yours as an answer, I can delete mine.

Comment: @holgac, aaahh, that is ok, +1 :)

Comment: If you were missing some include, you would have [compile time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time) error. But what you have is [run time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time) error. Basically kernel can't link some of functions you are using with actual functions in kernel code. @holgac explained pretty well why it's happening in his answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function [__class_create](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/class.c?v=3.18#L238%20%22__class_create) is exported only for GPL modules (exported with `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL`). So, you need to use a GPL license with `MODULE_LICENSE` macro to make use of that function. Same goes for other functions as well.

This should do the trick:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

To learn about what exporting is, take a look at [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2011/07/exporting-symbols-from-module.html). Basically, dynamic modules do not have access to variables and functions in kernel, and kernel needs to specify what to export, to enable access. That's the purpose of `EXPORT_SYMBOL` and `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` macros, which are used everywhere.

And the difference between `EXPORT_SYMBOL` and `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` is that the latter only reveals the function or the variable if the module is GPL licensed.

Comment: It's working... Can you refer me to a good explanation about what it is?

Comment: @Algosub See [LDD3 book, chapter 2](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf)., page 29.