# Getiing Unknown symbol ***_******(err 0) while reading or writing from linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I know that reading or writing(i/o) from kernel is a bad thing but under some circumstances I have to do that and while reading many sites I got the code from [things you should never do in kernel](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print) so thought of trying it. While making module.while compiling it was giving me

> WARNING: "sys_write" [/path/to/file/file.ko] undefined!
>   WARNING:"sys_open" [/path/to/file/file.ko] undefined!

but I thought of inserting the module while inserting the module I was getting

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module file.ko: Unknown symbol in
>   module

To get an answer for that I crawled through some sites([c-unkown symbol class create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578931/unknown-symbol-class-create-err-0)) but I had

> MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

in my module code and mean while searching I got the way to
make available the unknown symbols while making the modules. which is from
**Documenats/kbuild/modules.txt.**

Then I made

> make KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS='/home/lunako/Documents/ker_write/Module.symvers'

still no result. What I should do now ? Thanks

Comment: Please provide complete code for your module and and Makefile in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would discourage you to continue what you're doing, but if you insist, you need to export the `sys_open` function so it could be used by modules.
search for `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro

BTW, you need to recompile the kernel to make this symbol available for kernel modules.