# Unable to insert kernel module: Unknown symbol net_namespace_list

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel module that lists the network namespaces using the **for_each_net** and have written the following snippet which compiles fine:

```
rtnl_lock();
for_each_net(net)
   printk("network ns: %p\n",  net);
rtnl_unlock();
```

However when I try to insert the kernel module i get the following error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module kerNotification.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

The dmesg gives the additional error information:

```
[3561461.418499] kerNotification: Unknown symbol net_namespace_list (err 0)
```

The kallsyms shows that it has the symbol of this kernel function:

```
[josh@dev kernel_prog(keystone_admin)]# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep net_namespace_list
ffffffff81a203e0 R __ksymtab_net_namespace_list
ffffffff81a32bc0 r __kcrctab_net_namespace_list
ffffffff81a55452 r __kstrtab_net_namespace_list
ffffffff81b6b000 D net_namespace_lis
```

The Module.symvers is included in the makefile as KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS. Here is the Makefile:

```
obj-m += kerNotification.o

SYMBOLA=/usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/Module.symvers
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS= $(SYMBOLA)

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build $(KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Here is the complete logs when the make file is built with V=1:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/build /usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/Module.symvers M=/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `/usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/Module.symvers'.
mkdir -p /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog
   rm -f /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/built-in.o; ar rcsD /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/built-in.o
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.kerNotification.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(kerNotification)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(kerNotification)" -c -o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.tmp_kerNotification.o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.c
/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.c: In function ‘kerNotification_init’:
/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.c:37:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     struct net *net;
     ^
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.o"; fi; fi;
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.ko;) > /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/modules.order
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modpost
  find /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i ./Module.symvers -I /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/Module.symvers   -e /usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/Module.symvers -o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/Module.symvers   -w  -s -T -
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/.kerNotification.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(kerNotification.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(kerNotification)" -DMODULE  -c -o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.mod.o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_x86_64 -T ./scripts/module-common.lds --build-id  -o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.ko /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.o /home/cmmdocker/kernel_prog/kerNotification.mod.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.4.57-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unknown symbol \_\_class\_create (err 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578931/unknown-symbol-class-create-err-0)

Answer (score 1):

Issue was missing license. Below was added to get the expected result:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Referred the following answer from another query on stackoverflow for this: [unknown-symbol-class-create-err-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578931/unknown-symbol-class-create-err-0)

Answer (score 0):

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module kerNotification.ko: Unknown
>   symbol in module

You get the above error because the **net_namespace_list** is missing in the kernel. So you need to make sure to insert the module which it is defined. looking at the source code its declared in [net_namespace.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.2/source/net/core/net_namespace.c) and looking at the [Makefile](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.2/source/net/Makefile) it will when **CONFIG_NET** is enabled. Also when you have built your kernel image the System.map file should tell you if its declared in the kernel image which you  have built, something like below:

> cat System.map  | grep net_namespace_list
>
> 8041a888 r __ksymtab_net_namespace_list
>
> 8042b80c r __kstrtab_net_namespace_list
>
> 80464c08 D net_namespace_list

Comment: If the defined module is inserted and verified to be in the System.map of the kernel image built, on of the possible causes could be missing license as in this case. Refer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578931/unknown-symbol-class-create-err-0